# Why Community's age is 0

Tags: discussion, meta, profile-page, community-user

Simply interesting. On SO no age displayed, on MSO [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)'s age is 0.

> [image]

Why?

Comment: Probably just an oversight.

Comment: She's a newborn unicorn, isn't that obvious?

Comment: In light of a previous discussion I expect that account to be destroyed when noticed.

Comment: @Bart I give parental consent for Community to be a bot on our sites.

Comment: But seriously, looks like we show Community's age on all child meta sites, but not on main sites.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Probably because she's with other children there, so it's hard to hide.

Comment: @AnnaLear Other child metas do not currently show Community's age, only MSO.

Comment: @Gilles We do on Genealogy. I haven't spot-checked many metas.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ah, indeed, it seems to be a matter of the site's age. The cutoff is between [MVM&R](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (no age) and [Parenting](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (age 3). The new way makes sense to me — Community has the site's age.

Comment: On Stack Oferflow me Português, Community's age shows both on the main site and meta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade

Comment: I suggest "Why is Community's age 0?" as a proper question title.

Comment: Eh, was just going to report this. @Anna so no plan to fix this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I feel very strongly "meh" about this, to be honest. Although I am mildly curious why we have a birthday set for Community on metas and not main sites.

Comment: @AnnaLear isn't it as simple as NULL value in database?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, but 100+ databases plus checking to see where the birthdate comes from in the first place and making it, well, not. Might also just be a display issue. I'll take a look on Monday. Mostly I just forgot earlier. :)

Comment: Cheers @Anna count on you to squish this bug, meh or not meh. ;)

Comment: Since it represents the community, I suggest the age should be: `age = convert_to_dog_years(now() - so_launch_date);`. That way it'll seem more "senior" right? :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At some point in the last **mumble** years, the site creation DB script got updated to set Community's birthdate to current time, effectively making the bot the same age as the site.

Exhibit A: [recently launched Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and its [meta](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

We could go back and backfill the date on the sites that don't have it set, but personally, I'm okay with having this slight inconsistency. :)